# Remove repeating of options in selector using html and php

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to remove the repeating data from database in a selector options.For an example User inputs his/her own foods to the database, In the edit form all the foods will appear in the selector and the record is repeated there.It is impossible to use if else conditions cause we don't know the values of the user.Is there any way to do this.Please refer to the image

[image]

Comment: for remove duplicate name at the time of select you can use group by if database is like mysql

Comment: use javascript/jquery

Comment: If the select menu is populated with data from the database( as it appears to be ) then limit the output of the query - ie `select distinct name,id from table` etc

Comment: There's not enough context in your question to properly answer it, but it should most likely be solved at the database query level, as already suggested by Professor Abronsius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Hope it's Help you

```js
$(".select option").val(function(idx, val) {
  $(this).siblings('[value="'+ val +'"]').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select">
  <option value="">All</option>
  <option value="unilever">unilever</option>
  <option value="unilever">unilever</option><!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
  <option value="unilever">unilever</option><!-- will be removed since value is duplicate -->
  <option value="maliban">maliban</option> 
  <option value="alaris">alaris</option> 
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to take the option text than taking the value?

Comment: Value is the best way to remove a similar option because option text is not the same every time.